# Парсинг на Python + BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

**Вот код**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import csv
import time

def get_html(url):
    headers = {
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36 OPR/76.0.4017.177'
    }
    html = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
    return html

def write_csv(data):
    with open('wild_pars.csv', 'a') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=';')
        writer.writerow((data['class'],
                         data['category'],
                         data['brand_name'],
                         data['good_name'],
                         data['price'],
                         data['url']))



def fix_brand_name(text):
    name = text.split('/')[0].strip()
    return name


def fix_price(text):
    price = text.replace(' ', '').replace('₽', '')
    return price


def pars_content(class__, category, small_url):
    root = 'https://www.wildberries.ru'

    for page in range(1, 5000):
        pagination = f'?page={page}'
        url = small_url + pagination
        html = get_html(url)
        time.sleep(2)
        soup = BS(html, 'lxml')
        contents = soup.find_all('div', class_='dtList-inner')
        if len(contents) == 0:
            break
        else:
            for content in contents:
                try:
                    brand_name = content.find('strong', class_='brand-name c-text-sm').text.strip()
                    fbrand_name = fix_brand_name(brand_name)
                except:
                    fbrand_name = 'Брэнд отсутствует'

                try:
                    good_name = content.find('span', class_='goods-name c-text-sm').text.strip()
                except:
                    good_name = 'Название отсутствует'

                try:
                    price = content.find('span', class_='price').find('ins', class_='lower-price').text.strip()
                    fprice = fix_price(price)
                except:
                    price = content.find('span', class_='lower-price').text.strip()
                    fprice = fix_price(price)

                try:
                    href_content = root + content.find('a', class_='ref_goods_n_p j-open-full-product-card').get('href').strip()
                except:
                    href_content = root + content.find('a', class_='ref_goods_n_p j-open-full-product-card is-adult').get(
                        'href').strip()

                content_data = {'class': class__,
                                'category': category,
                                'brand_name': fbrand_name,
                                'good_name': good_name,
                                'price': fprice,
                                'url': href_content}

                write_csv(content_data)

def main(url):
    html = get_html(url)
    soup = BS(html, 'lxml')
    all_menu = soup.find('ul', class_='menu-burger__main-list').find_all(
        class_='menu-burger__main-list-item j-menu-main-item')

    all_menu_dict = {}

    for i in all_menu:
        name = i.find('a').text
        href = i.find('a').get('href')
        all_menu_dict[name] = href

    for key in all_menu_dict:

        try:
            html = get_html(all_menu_dict[key])
            soup = BS(html, 'lxml')
            all_catalog = soup.find('ul', class_='maincatalog-list-2').find_all('a')

            for i in all_catalog:
                root = 'https://www.wildberries.ru'
                category = i.text
                href = root + i.get('href')
                pars_content(key, category, href)
        except:
            pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    url = 'https://www.wildberries.ru'
    main(url)
```

Написал парсер товаров с wildberries. По моему должен работать нормально,все проверял несколько раз,но он почему то все равно работает не корректно.Проблема такая,парсер собирает товары по категориям с магазина (пример: категория женщинам - одежда(спарсил),затем женщинам-большие размеры и т.д.).Но парсер почему то после категории женщинам-одежда парсить начинает уже следующую мужчинам-одежда. Т.е. большая часть товаров "женщинам " не парсится. Не понимаю почему так,ссылки проверял,поступают корректные, но парсер почему то перепрыгивает множество категорий...Помогите разобраться
[image: Вот как сохраняются данные][image: А вот сколько еще категорий должен спарсить,ссылки на них поступают,но почему то данные не собираются]

[image: Это пример того,что ссылки на категории попадают,но почему то не парсятся]

Comment: Я прошелся быстро через дебаггер работает как надо, но есть некоторые замечания по парсеру:
1 глухим except обрабатывать ошибки опасно, так как не предсказать в чём проблемы программы, лучше оборачивать через try: ... except Exception as e: и печатать/записывать куда-нибудь ошибки (e), предполагаю в продолжительной работе программы и кроется проблема.
2 Запрос лучше делать через сессию и куда-нибудь объект сессии серелизовать, через него легко подхватишь cookie файлы с сайта и тем самым будет лучшая эмуляция легитимных запросов.

Comment: @Georgiy Спасибо вам большое,учту.На голом except несколько раз погорел...Но вот как отыскать эту проблему все равно до сих пор не понял.

Comment: Библиотека logging в помощь или печать ошибки через библиотеку traceback и по полученным ошибкам корректировать

Comment: @Georgiy хорошо, понял, спасибо.